# How to create new string each time new item is created?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, listbox

I have a textbox, an add button, a create button and a listbox. Currently when I enter text in the textbox and click the add button, the text then appears in the listbox. When I click the create button it shows the text/item from the listbox in a messagebox. But I want to be able to enter 4 or 5 items in the listbox and when I click the create button, it to show a random item from the listbox in the messagebox.

For example, say Dean, Sam, Jess are the items in the listbox, when I click the create button I want it to show one of these items in the messagebox but I want it to be a random item each time I click the create Button and only one item at a time. But the items in the listbox are not always going to have the same names so I cant set a word to a string as I want the user to be able to enter what they like into the listbox. So I can only string what is entered into the textbox.

Here is some code, I have left code for the listbox empty as I am not sure what to, but I know that may be where I need to work

```
    private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stringname = textBoxname.Text;
        textBoxname.Clear();
        listboxname.Items.Add(stringname);            
    }

    private void listboxname_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void buttoncreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(stringname);
    }
```

Comment: Let me understand better, you want to enter "Dean, Sam, Jess" and when you press Add have just one added and the others discarded, or do you want to save the other two for future adding?

Comment: No, them names are an example of what could have already be entered into the listbox. The add button adds text from the textbox to the listbox. I want the create button to show a random item/text I have entered into the listbox in a messagebox. There could 1000 items in the listbox, I want the create button to show one of them and a random one each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand good You just want to show random from ListBox every time?

Use random number to select random item.

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber  = random.Next(1, listboxname.Items.Count);
listboxname.Select();
listboxname.SelectedItem = listboxname.Items[randomNumber];
MessageBox.Show(listboxName.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Comment: This is close but int randomNumber  = random.Next(1, strings.Items.Count); is causing problems, the name string does not exist in current context

Comment: Ah yes I should have noticed that too! But now another error. MessageBox.Show(listboxname.SelectedItem); is telling me it cannot convert object to string

Comment: Sorry I not work long in C#, try MessageBox.Show(listboxName.SelectedItem.ToString());

I try, it Work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your word separator is a space:

```
Random rand=new Random();

private void buttoncreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Splits your string on space, turning it in an array
        var arrayOfWords=(textBoxname.Text).Split(' ');
        //Picks a random word on the array
        MessageBox.Show(arrayOfWords[rand.Next(arrayOfWords.Count()]);
    }
```